# Re-authorization for an app to send gmail

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, gmail-api

under what situations (other than someone revoking permission of changing their gmail password) would a user need to re-authorization an app's access to their gmail data? My app stores and uses a refresh token to maintain a current access token, but my users are occasionally still asked to authorize from scratch, and sometimes this then fails and only works again when they reset their browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

Causes for a refresh token to expire.

1. user revokes access.
2. User changes password and your using a gmail scope
3. refresh token has not been used in six months.
4. You can have a max of 50 outstanding refresh tokens for a user. So if the user is requesting a new refresh token often make sure to store the newest as the once you hit 51 the oldest one available will be expired.

That should be about it unless you consider the bug of fall 2015 which caused a bunch of refresh tokens to expire due to daylight savings time.  (That was a fun day)

Comment: Hi. Well none of those apply, so I’m quite confused.

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on why this keeps happening? At random intervals everyone using my app to send emails via the gmail api needs to reauthorize, although none of the conditions kindly stated above by Daimto apply. And then, when they do try to reauthorize they get an error ("Something Went Wrong"). They then have to open their browser, clear settings, then re-authorize before it will work. I'm using google's own authorization broker object, so in my mind that effectively rules out a coding issue on my part.

Comment: I would personally guess that its number 4 your not storing the most recent refresh token. But it really depends on the type of app your using.

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm not storing anything explicitly, it's all being done by Google's Authorization Broker. Here's the code:

UserCredential credential; 
using (FileStream credentialsfile = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + @"/credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
                string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/SJGmailAPI.json");
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(credentialsfile).Secrets, Scopes, senderemailaddress, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }
            bool rc = AuthTest.TestAuthorisation(credential,senderemailaddress,ApplicationName);

So is Google's own code storing the wrong refresh token then?
```